# How to create dataframe in python using columns from multiple DB tables

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am just starting to learn python. I need to write test automation code quickly such that it will verify different columns from different tables in same DB schema with a columns in csv file.

I found some help which talks about converting one table values to data frame but not how to fetch and convert the columns from different tables to single data frame.

Table T1 has following columns -

```
T1C1, T1C2, T1C3
```

Table T2 has following columns -

```
T2C1, T2C2, T2C3
```

Table T3 has following columns -

```
T3C1, T3C4, T3C5
```

My requirement is to create a data frame from all above columns like -

```
T1C1, T1C2, T1C3,T2C1, T2C2, T2C3,T3C1, T3C4, T3C5
```

So that I can compare with the columns in csv -

```
C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9

T1C1 = C1, T1C2 = C2,….
```

Comment: Do all 3 tables have the same rows and indexes?

Comment: are your values held as columns? and does your csv file match the above? it might be easier to unpivot the dataframe first. additionally, are you reading directly from your sqlDB via pandas/sqlalchemy/pydobc?

Comment: I am assuming the tables are in a DB and not in different CSV files. In this case, use SQL to get all the necessary columns (you can use pyodbc/sqlalchemy etc to directly run the query through python as well). Then use pandas (pd.read_csv() if you have csv files or pd.read_sql() if you are using python to query the DB)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

first I would declare a list of your table names,

```
tables = ['T1','T2','T3']
```

then we can create a dictionary (key value pair python object) to hold your items, with the key as the table name and the value as the column name.

```
table_dict = {}
for table in tables:
    df = pd.read_sql(f"SELECT TOP 1 * from {table}",con=engine) # assuming you're connected to your sqldB.
    table_dict[f'{table}'] = df.columns.tolist()
```

if we print the dict it will give us something like

```
print(table_dict)
{'T1': ['T1C2', 'T1C3'], 'T2': ['T2C2', 'T2C3'], 'T3': ['T3C4', 'T3C5']}
```

we then pass this into a dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(table_dict)
df = pd.melt(df,var_name='table',value_name='columns')
print(df)
     table columns
0    T1    T1C2
1    T1    T1C3
2    T2    T2C2
3    T2    T2C3
4    T3    T3C4
5    T3    T3C5
```

I'm going to assume your csv is in a tabular format :

```
print(csv_cols)
    csv_cols
0   C1
1   C2
2   C3
3   C4
4   C5
5   C6
6   C7
7   C8
8   C9
```

I'm going to assume that you can easily get your unique column names to match your csv column.

for ease sake, I've just sliced the values from your columns but you will probably need to use some regex.

```
df['csv_cols'] = df['columns'].str[-2:]
```

finally a merge to get the common values.

```
matches = pd.merge(df,csv_cols,on='csv_cols',how='inner')
# use the join that gets you your result.
print(matches)
    table columns csv_cols
0    T1    T1C2       C2
1    T2    T2C2       C2
2    T1    T1C3       C3
3    T2    T2C3       C3
4    T3    T3C4       C4
5    T3    T3C5       C5
```

Comment: Thank you Datanovice for the detail reply. I will try this.

Comment: No problemo let me know if you need anymore assistance

Comment: Hello Datanovice, In your example - you are considering all the columns in the table. But I need to cherry pick the columns from each table. These columns may not have matching key with other table. So I am thinking of creating a dataframe for each table and then join all the DFs. But when dealing with large data, will my approach work? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: are the columns that you need from your tables the same or different?

Comment: They will be different. So it's like rather than inner joining those columns in DB, I will be fetching those columns from DB and joining in DF. So there will be at least one key on which I will joining those columns.

Comment: do you have a log table with all the relevant tables declared? you can pass in the relevant tables within the `read_sql` query but need more information your original post really doesn't make that apparent at all.. also you're not making it clear (remember no one here knows your requirement or project)